# Fetch Data from database to Fullcalendar.io using Json

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

In the following code I am trying to select events from a table in a database to show it in the open source calendar Fullcalendar.io

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (var db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var select = from cevent in db.EventTables
                         select new {
                             id = cevent.Id,
                             start = cevent.Start_Time,
                             end = cevent.End_Time
                         };
            var rows = select.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }            
    }
```

The thing is that i use the events as follow to fetch the data as described in documentation:

```
events: function () {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'GetEvents', 
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log("data is not fetshed from database");
            }
        }); 
    },
```

and when looking in the console at the browser following picture is the result:

[image: Returned Result from Json Controller]

And thats how start and end time are saved in db 
[image: starttime and end time format in db]
the start and end date format are wrong and I am not able to fix it, can anyone help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the date in an ISO8601 date string for start and end params. As stated on http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/

The code should be:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    using (var db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var events = from cevent in db.EventTables
                     select cevent;
        var rows = events.ToList().Select(cevent => new {
                         id = cevent.Id,
                         start = cevent.Start_Time.AddSeconds(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
                         end = cevent.End_Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
                     }).ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }            
}
```

I recommend adding 1 second to the start time, to avoid conflicts on events like:
Event1 10:00 to 11:00
Event2 11:00 to 11:30

For fullcalendar.io Event2 is overlaping with Event1, becuase of the last second of Even1 and the first second of Event2.

Comment: i tried this bro  but unfortuanlty i am getting  this error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can you confirm that start_time and end_time on cevent are DataTime?

Comment: Yes they are, i saved start and end time as DateTime in DB

Comment: Can you debug the action method and see on which line is it throwing the error?

Comment: The action method is excuted with no error, the 500 error am getting is in the Chrome browser.

Comment: 500 error are internal server error. That error has to be on your server side. If you have access to your IIS, please verify the log to gather more information about the error? Eventhough this is getting a bit off topic of your original question.

Comment: actually i run the debugg now and i noticed that this line return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); is not excuting when i added this two lines  start = cevent.Start_Time.AddSeconds(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
                                 end = cevent.End_Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Comment: The problem is in this two lines start = cevent.Start_Time.AddSeconds(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"), end = cevent.End_Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"), it works when i delete them.. but i still the wrong date fromat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96300/discussion-between-cat-clan-and-moji).

Comment: Thank you for ur help bro @Cat_Clan